# Joining output out of different commands into columns side-by-side

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have multiple commands for which I want to print the output of each command in columns.

Here is the commands and output I have:

```
echo "Batch 1 list" >> out.txt
ssh -T mqm@mqprb01 "echo 'DIS CLUSQMGR(*)'|runmqsc" |awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' >> out.txt
echo "===============================================================">> out.txt
echo "Batch 2 list" >> out.txt
ssh -T mqm@mqprn01 "echo 'DIS CLUSQMGR(*)'|runmqsc" |awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' >> out.txt
echo "===============================================================">> out.txt
echo "Batch 3 list">> out.txt
ssh -T mqm@mqprl01 "echo 'DIS CLUSQMGR(*)'|runmqsc" | awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' >> out.txt
echo "===============================================================">> out.txt
```

Here is the output:

```
Batch list
F111
F211
F311
F411
F511
F9P1
F9P4
F9P6
F9P7
FA11

===============================================================
Batch 2 list
A111
B211
V311
F411
B511
B9P1
NA11
FB11
CD11

===============================================================
 batch 2 list
C111
C211
R311
Y411
E511
B9P1
EA11
AB11
ND11
```

I would like to see the output in this format:

```
Batch 1 list(count) Batch 2 list(count)  Batch 3 list(count)
F111                    A111               C111
F211                    B211               C211
F311                    V311               R311
F411                    F411               Y411
F511                    B511               E511
F9P1                    B9P1               B9P1
F9P4                    NA11               EA11
F9P6                    FB11               AB11
F9P7                    CD11               ND11
FA11
```

Count is number of entries in that column.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the result into separate files and then use the `paste` command to tailor them together laterally:

```
paste out1 out2 out3 > out.formatted
```

This is the output you will get:

```
Batch list  Batch 2 list    batch 2 list
F111    A111    C111
F211    B211    C211
F311    V311    R311
F411    F411    Y411
F511    B511    E511
F9P1    B9P1    B9P1
F9P4    NA11    EA11
F9P6    FB11    AB11
F9P7    CD11    ND11
FA11
```

Getting the counts is a little tricky. Instead of putting the headers in the beginning, add them while pasting, like this:

```
export count1=$(grep -c '^' out1) # need to export so that it is available to `cat`s below which run in subshells
export count2=$(grep -c '^' out2)
export count3=$(grep -c '^' out3)
paste <(cat - <<< "Batch list ($count1)" out1) <(cat - <<< "Batch list ($count2)" out2) <(cat - <<< "Batch list ($count3)" out3) > out.formatted
```

- `cat -` -> makes sure cat reads from stdin coming from here string `<<<` as well as the file

Comment: output is not clean or its not aligned into coloumns. i used column -t to format it and I can work with it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

better to get the each outputs in separet files and merge them as 1

```
paste out1.log out2.log out3.log|expand --tabs=1>final_out.log
```